# gammu-smsd-inject dont send UTF-8 characters æøå

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

When issuing this command **gammu-smsd-inject TEXT 123-text "abcæøå"** I will receive a SMS without æøå. This has obvious something with character encoding to do, I have tried several options to the command, -unicode -utf8

gammu is configured with file-backend and not database, does this have something to say

Answer (score 0):

As an immediate solution you can [force gammu to use unicode](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#option-OutboxFormat):

```
[smsd]
OutboxFormat = unicode
TransmitFormat = unicode
```

Then switch `TransmitFormat` to `auto` if the above works.

Answer (score 0):

try to add an arg `-unicode` to the end of your command